# PHP Recurently check if time is in a range, when the range spans more than one day

Tags: php, datetime

There are a lot of SO questions showing you how to check if a date-time is within a range, but there is not much to help when you want to do recurrently and the date range spans more than one day.

As an example, how do you check if its between 22:00 on a Tuesday and 07:30 on the following Thrusday? And how do you do that week in week out?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight If I put what I tried how would it make sense to ask an answer my own question [as encouraged on SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) Anyway, "how would you check if its between 22:00 on a Tuesday and 07:30 on the following Thursday?" seems minimal, complete and verifiable to me. I notice that your "what you have tried so far" link is off site, can you point to any SO guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for PHP's DataTime class accepts the relative argument `this xxxday`, which can be used to give you the next 'xxxday' relative to the current time.

So for example, `new DateTime('next friday')` will give you a datetime object representing 00:00:00 on the next Friday relative to the current day. If the current day **is** Friday, then that is the date which will be returned.

So if you define

```
$end = new DateTime(next thursday 07:30);
```

then `$end` is a DateTime object representing 22:00 on the next Tuesday from the current time, or 20:00 for today if today is a Tuesday. Then you can take the interval off the end to get the start with

```
$start = clone $end;
$start = $end->sub(new DateInterval('P1DT9H30M'));
```

which gives you a DateTime object 1day, 9hours and 30 minutes prior to 07:30 on the **next** Thursday from the current time, or 22:00 on the Tuesday before the next Thursday from the current time.

Then you can get the current date time and see if its between the start and end date times:

```
$now = new DateTime();
if( $now >= $start && $now <= $end ) {
    //In interval
}
```